# How do we do junit for java8 Function,Predicate,Bifunction

Tags: lambda, junit, java-8, stream, mockito

I am trying to migrate my application to java 8 from java 7 and trying to make use of the conciseness provided by using java 8 lambdas. but unit testing became a nightmare for me as I cannot refer Function/Predicate from testing class. I have below questions:

My previous code:

```
public String myMethod(int v1){
     //Some logic
}
```

Usign java8:

```
Fucntion<Integer,String> myMethod = (i) -> {
    //Same some logic
};
```

So Unit testing became a night are for me in th above case. I am using Junit,Mockito for unit testing.

TestClass:

```
@RunWith(JunitMockitoRunner.class)
public class TestClass{
    @InjectMock
    Testclass mock;

// want to test my method which i am trying to write using Fucntion<I,O>

}
```

Also will the performace be better if i go with java7 way having a method instead of lambda or fucntional Interface?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Lambda expressions aren't meant to replace methods; they're used to pass _behavior_ around. You know all those places you'd use an anonymous class just to implement a single abstract method (e.g. `Runnable`s, listeners, callbacks, etc.)? That's where you should use lambdas.

Answer (score -1):

If both the method and the function are defined in the same scope, then I don't see much difference in testing them.
If `myMethod` is defined as an instance variable you can simply invoke it and assert the result, like this:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
    Fucntion<Integer,String> myMethod = (i) -> {
        //Same some logic
    };
}

class ClassUnderTestTest {
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = // instantiate object
    String actualResult = classUnderTest.myMethod(1);

    assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

If `ClassUnderTest` has some other properties on which `myMethod` depends, you can mock them using Mockito.